# changing bits in hex value, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bit

I'm curious, is it possible in vb.net? I want to change bit6 and bit7 from value that user will write in hex. The algorithm:

> bit6 = bit0 xor bit1 xor bit2 xor bit3
>
> bit7 = NOT (bit1 xor bit3 xor bit4 xor bit5)

So for exmaple if user write &H55, code will change it to &H85. Is it possible at all?

Comment: There is such a thing as a BitArray class in the ,Net framework. Give it a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea:

```
        Dim a = &H55

        Dim b As New BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(a))

        Dim c As New BitArray(8)

        c.Set(0, b(0))
        c.Set(1, b(1))
        c.Set(2, b(2))
        c.Set(3, b(3))
        c.Set(4, b(4))
        c.Set(5, b(5))
        c.Set(6, b(0) Xor b(1) Xor b(2) Xor b(3))
        c.Set(7, Not (b(1) Xor b(3) Xor b(4) Xor b(5)))

        Dim c2(7) As Byte

        c.CopyTo(c2, 0)

        Dim d = BitConverter.ToUInt32(c2, 0)
```

But i'm not sure how you get 0x85 from 0x55 by this operaions.

```
0x55: 0101 0101
0x85: 1000 0101
b6 is 0
b7 is 0
res:  0001 0101 (0x15)
```

to get from 0x55 to 0x85 you would have to change b4,b6,b7

Comment: was my mistake with bits :)